# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, nosuchelementexception

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Dev environment
        driver.Url = /*URL*/;

        var trialGroupName = driver.FindElement(By.Name("TrialGroupName")); 
        trialGroupName.SendKeys(/*trial group name */);

        var userName = driver.FindElement(By.Name("UserName"));
        userName.SendKeys(/*username*/);

        var password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("UserPassword"));
        password.SendKeys(/*password*/);

        var loginButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Ok"));
        loginButton.Click();

        //Find and click on Browse tab
        var browseTab = driver.FindElement(By.Id("17"));
        browseTab.Click();
    }
}
```

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"17"}
>     (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)'

Here's the inspect information:

```
<td>
<a id="17" class="defaultMenu initMenu" href="javascript:onMenuHref(17)" notran="">Browse</a>
</td>
```

I've also tried running it with the XPath (both the short version from Chrome and the long version from FireBug) and I receive the same error. I've tried adding in an implicit wait and a Thread.Sleep() but still received the same error. Also tried starting on a different field and tabbing to it and then it gave me the same exception but on the new field. I also tried playing around with cssSelector this morning and couldn't get that to work either. I did try to do an explicit wait but I'll be honest, I'm still trying to digest and understand it as waits are a new concept and I don't fully understand it, so I don't think I'm doing it right.

I'm a beginner, and I'm currently just trying to write the script to get it to the actual page that needs testing. I've been teaching myself some coding and selenium as I'm the only QA person at my company right now and I really think we could benefit from automation. This portion of the page isn't actually programmed by us it's done by a third party who hosts the system we use so I'm limited to what I see in the inspect.

(I commented out the user login information and URL because it is for internal use only and the page can't be reached outside of our systems anyways. Also I'm pretty sure I'm not allowed to do so by my employer).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, or any additional resources I can use. I've been using google mostly so there may be other pages you are aware of that could help me that I haven't found yet.

Comment: Does that link only appear after you clicked on the Login button? if yes, add a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);` just after `loginButton.Click();` to wait 5000 ms and if that works, read up on http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp for how to Wait on elements to become available in the DOM.

Comment: Thread.Sleep() is okay for debugging but not a best practice. There are different load times on different devices, so you end up waiting too long (tests take longer to run than they should) or not long enough (tests fail).

Comment: I added that and it still throws the same exception. I can see it load the page and can see the Browse tab on the page, it does the wait, then closes the window and throws the exception. I am going to read through that page though, since Waits are still a new concept to me.

Answer (score 3):

The login button takes you to a new page, which you need to wait for it to load. Try using an [explicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) to wait for the tab to be clickable. The timeout is 10 seconds in the following example, so modify that as needed.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement browseTab = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("17")));
```

Comment: I'm now receiving

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Timed out after 10 seconds
  Source=WebDriver.Support
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
   at WebDriverDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\HSA7439\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WebDriverDemo\WebDriverDemo\Program.cs:line 38
**Followed by** 
Inner Exception 1:
NoSuchElementException again

Comment: @MeganSmoak - Are you sure this id is static. You shouldn't identify element by id as the id's keep changing. Can you verify your xpath using chrome console or firebug ?

Comment: Two Things: 1. The wait might not be long enough. Try upping it to 30. 2. The ID could be dynamic. Use a selector that doesn't rely on an ID. One way to accomplish this is to edit the HTML in the DOM Explorer of Chrome and remove the id attribute entirely. Then right-click (in the DOM Explorer) on the element and select "Copy" > "Copy Selector" (for CSS Selector).

Comment: @Saurabh If the users permissions/role is set correctly then that tab is always present and each time I've opened it, it has used the Id of "17". I used both Chrome's shortened XPath, and the full XPath through Firebug, both gave me the same exception.

Comment: @TimothyCope I had upped the wait to 30 seconds and received the same time out error. I will try your second option as soon as I'm able too.

Comment: @MeganSmoak- Not sure what language is the application written in. Could you try using Actions class. Here is sample code: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/mouse-hover-action/